# Django logging configuration star notation

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging

Let's say I have the following Django logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "WARNING",
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "app1.management.commands": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "app2.management.commands": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "app3.management.commands": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}
```

Notice how I'm repeating the same configuration for all app management commands. I'd love to be able to consolidate into a single entry like so:

```
"*.management.commands": {
    "handlers": ["console"],
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "propagate": False,
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Is this possible or do I need to repeat the config for all apps?

Comment: I don't think you can. Logging goes through the tree one component at a time, starting from the left, and wouldn't know that there would be "management.commands" further down the tree. "*" would match "django" and any other log name. But you could write a single dict and have each logger reference that one, and even auto generate the keys.

Comment: `'loggers': {'django': {...}, **{f'{a}.management.commands': {...} for a in ('app1', 'app2', 'app3')}}` - this way you declare the inner dictionary only once. You can even use `INSTALLED_APPS` to be more DRY and avoid two lists of apps in separate places.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can construct the relevant dict dynamically, using an approach such as this:

```
from pprint import pprint

class DynamicLoggerDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data, common, apps):
        super().__init__(data)
        for app in apps:
            key = f'{app}.management.commands'
            self[key] = common
            
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "WARNING",
    },
    "loggers": DynamicLoggerDict({
            "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": False
        }},  {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        }, ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']),
}

pprint(LOGGING)
```

When run, the above prints

```
{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'handlers': {'console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'}},
 'loggers': {'app1.management.commands': {'handlers': ['console'],
                                          'level': 'DEBUG',
                                          'propagate': False},
             'app2.management.commands': {'handlers': ['console'],
                                          'level': 'DEBUG',
                                          'propagate': False},
             'app3.management.commands': {'handlers': ['console'],
                                          'level': 'DEBUG',
                                          'propagate': False},
             'django': {'handlers': ['console'],
                        'level': 'INFO',
                        'propagate': False}},
 'root': {'handlers': ['console'], 'level': 'WARNING'},
 'version': 1}
```